# Yii CArrayDataProvider Keyfield As Button Id In CGridView

Tags: php, ajax, yii

My issue is two-fold. First, I'm unable to correctly set the keyField for CArrayDataProvider, all I'm getting back is a string instead of a value. Second, I'm trying to use the keyField inside of CArrayDataProvider to set an id on the button in each row inside of CGridView. The reason I want to do this is so that I can pass the id value onward to an ajax function (if there's a better way to do this in Yii, I'm all ears). Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

I also posted this question once on Yii's forums. I normally wouldn't repost, but I have had a hard time getting answers there, as opposed to stack overflow, you guys are the best! [Here's the link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/53819-carraydataprovider-keyfield-as-button-id-in-cgridview/page__p__247604#entry247604) to my original post if anyone is interested.

Here is how I'm building the array that I'm using as my RAW data:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
        $tableRow = array("id"=>$item["Id"], "Organization"=>$item["Organization"], "Roles"=>$item["Roles"]);
        $return_items[] = $tableRow;
}
```

Here is the CArrayDataProvider setup I'm using. I noticed that 'keyField' is not being given the id value, just the string 'id':

```
$dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($return_items, array(
        'keyField'=>'id',
        'sort'=>array(
                'attributes'=>array(
                        'Organization',
                        'Roles',
                ),
        ),
        'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>10,
        ),
));
```

Lastly, here is the CGridView I'm trying to setup in the view. All that appears on the button is the id tag, but no value:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$authItems,
        'columns'=>array(
                'Organization',
                'Roles',
                array('name'=>'', 
                          'type'=>'raw', 
                          'htmlOptions'=>array('id'=>'id'),
                          'value'=>'CHtml::button("Edit Roles", array("data-toggle"=>"modal", "data-target"=>"#roles-modal"))'), 
        ),
));
```

Comment: In your resultset you already have an 'id' field, remove 'keyField'=>'id' from your $dataProvider definition

Comment: @Alejandro Thank you for the quick response. I gave that a try, and I still don't think it's setting the keyField. A print_r of the CArrayDataProvider shows that `[keyField]=>id, [rawData] => array(array(values), array(values), etc)`. The id tag has also disappeared from the button, now there is nothing.

Comment: Just a loud thought! Try removing the `'name'=>''` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try passing it via CHtml::button which you have already applied. E.g.

```
'value'=>'CHtml::button("Edit Roles", array(
            "id"=>$data["id"],
            "data-toggle"=>"modal",
            "data-target"=>"#roles-modal"
          ))'),
```